# Retrieve email subject from file via bash

Tags: bash, email, sed

I've a shell script which downloads files from the servers mail folder to a NAS devices so the client has copies made locally with a backup.

The files are saved as **11469448248.H15587P19346.smtp.x14.eu_2,S** files.
I've changed the extension to standard .eml format so email clients can read them from disc.

```
for f in *.smtp.x14.eu_2,S; do
#sed "9q;d" $f
#tail -n+9 $f | head -n1
mv -- "$f" "${f%.smtp.x14.eu_2,S}.eml";
done
```

As you can see I've tried to use the **sed** and **tail** command to get the 9th line from the file; problem is that the subject isn't always on the 9th line and the file names don't say much of its content.

I'm trying to get the files names to be in a understandable format, so I figured the subject could be helpful.

On the nth line of the email file is a line that begins with **Subject: PD: the subject**

Im trying to find this line fet rid of **Subject: PD:** and leave the rest as the ne file name

Comment: Please be more precise. What exactly you want to do? If the thing you are looking for is not always in 9th line then you need to find some pattern.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a link to a definition of the format, or give us a good example of it.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the outcome file name I wish to achieve

Comment: The extension of a file has no bearing on whether it is readable by a particular application or not.

Comment: The extension is not important. The important thing is to rename the file name to be understandable for a human.

Comment: I hope you are not renaming files inside a live maildir hierarchy because many parts of the file name are important for maintaining that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is **wrong** but implements what you seem to be asking.

```
subj=$(sed -n '/^Subject: PD *//!d;p;q;/^$/q' "$f")
```

The problem with this is that it succeeds in the trivial case, but fails when you have a MIME RFC2047-encoded `Subject:` header, and (more trivially) when the `Subject:` header spans more than a single line.

I would approach this with a slightly more modern programming language.  It's not quite a one-liner, but it's easy enough with Python.

```
subj=$(./emailsubj.py "$f")
```

where `emailsubj.py` contains something more or less like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from email.parser import Parser
from email.header import Header, decode_header
from sys import argv

for filename in argv[1:]:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as handle:  # handle file not found etc?
        message = Parser().parse(handle)
    try:
        subj = ''.join([frag.decode(enc) if enc else frag
            for frag, enc in decode_header(message['subject'])])
    except HeaderParseError, UnicodeDecodeError:
        subj = message['subject']   # maybe warn about error?
    print(subj)
```

(Remember to `chmod +x emailsubj.py`, obviously.)

This retrieves the entire `Subject:` header and seems like a good design for a modular tool. If you want to remove a prefix after extracting the header, the shell has simple facilities for [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) which do exactly that.  For example,

```
echo "${subj#PD:\ }"
```

displays the value of `$subj` with any prefix `PD:`  removed from the front of the value.

---

The above was written for Python 2.7.
In Python 3.6+, a much simpler version is sufficient. The following exercises the Python 3.6+ revamped `email` library (which for the time being requires you to name an explicit `policy`, but) which is significantly simpler and more versatile.

```
from email import message_from_binary_file
from email.policy import default

from sys import argv

for filename in argv[1:]:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as handle:  # handle file not found etc?
        message = message_from_binary_file(handle, policy=default)
    print(message['subject'])
```

With Python 3, the output on any sane platform should be fine simply with `print`. Of course, if your terminal can't print Unicode (in which case you are probably on Windows) it could fail for that reason.

Comment: `formail` from the Procmail suite handles wrapped headers, but doesn't do anything about RFC2047 encoding.

Comment: OK. Thanks for this. I'll do this with python (that will be my first py script ;)

Comment: I should upgrade it to Python 3 but not quite there yet.  Reading email as bytes and then decoding into text where an encoding is defined is sort of wacky in Python. Maybe the simplest solution would be to fake it with `encoding='latin-1'` and then dropping to US-ASCII where pertinent. But in the meantime, this Python 2 snippet should work just fine for you.

Comment: The script works for the most part getting an **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0141' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)** error but the solution is very nice, so I'm working on it a little more.

Comment: Sounds like your terminal is not set up for Unicode output.  If you are on U*x try `LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8` before calling the script.  On some ungodly Microsoft platforms, I hear `chcp 65000` might or might not help.

Comment: OK I'll try that. Thank you

Comment: IN your script I've added this **decode_header(message['subject'].encode("utf-8"))** so the file names are ok in linux/unix. Now I'm trying to find a way to make them readable in windows (samba share). But that's another tale