# file names are unreadable in windows after copying from ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, bash, utf-8

Hello I've a problem that's a continuation from this [Retrieve email subject from file via bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457380/retrieve-email-subject-from-file-via-bash/39464990#39464990)

I've managed to make the renaming to work with the python script, the smb/windows share is mounted via fstab

```
//192.168.0.11/share/temp /media/share cifs username=username,password=password,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

The file names are all ok under linux but when I open the list in windows I see files that are like **PHBM4Q~8.EML**

This is the script that renames the files

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from email.parser import Parser
from email.header import Header, decode_header
from sys import argv
import codecs
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

for filename in argv[1:]:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as handle:  # handle file not found etc?
        message = Parser().parse(handle)
    try:
        subj = ''.join([frag.decode(enc) if enc else frag
            for frag, enc in decode_header(message['subject'])])
    except HeaderParseError, UnicodeDecodeError:
        subj = message['subject']   # maybe warn about error?
    print(subj)
```

I use rsync to copy the files

```
rsync -r  -v --progress -s $LOCALDIR $REMOTEDIR
```

Any ideas would be helpful as I think I've tried anything that google has to offer with no lock. And readable file names under windows are crucial.

Comment: so its the `rsync` that is assigning MS-Dos compatible names? Good luck.

Comment: So, when you mount the smb directory, if you `ls` it, does it already have the shortened filenames?

Comment: Yes the file names are readable. Also when i make right mouse click in windows and properties/details the file name is also normal

Answer (score 1):

So the problem wasn't the character encoding, but the final file name contained not allowed characters in the file name.

This post was useful https://serverfault.com/questions/124611/special-characters-in-samba-filenames. And in the python script i just added

```
print(subj.translate(None,'\/:*?"|<>'))
```